# "Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301" when building ionic app

Tags: java, cordova, ionic-framework

I have tried every which way to declare JAVA_HOME in my system variables, but I keep getting the following error when running 'ionic Cordova build --release android'

```
Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK version 8 installed.
You can get it from the following location:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_301
```

I've tried appending it with "bin", I've tried wrapping C: Program Files (x86) in double quotes, I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling java, and I always get the same error. When I run echo %JAVA_HOME% it gives me:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_301
```

How can I figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Two things. It says couldn't run `javac`, so make sure `javac` is in the `PATH`. And: try maybe installing JDK8 into a folder without spaces, like `C:\jdk8` or something.

Comment: javac is in the bin folder of that path. I will try moving it

Comment: I know it's in the `bin`. The question would be - it's a common problem - if the `bin`  is in the `PATH` environment variable. Windows looks up the executable by looking into the `PATH` variable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see a couple of problems here. The following instructions should help you resolve the issue:

1. The installation path has `x86` which suggests that you have installed a 32-bit version of JDK. If your OS is 64 bit (which is mostly the case), download and install the 64 bit JDK.
2. While installing, the installer gives you an opportunity to change the installation location. The default suggested location has space that may be problematic and therefore I recommend you change it to something like `C:\jdk`.
3. Append the path of JDK `bin` folder to the `PATH` environment variable e.g. if the path of `bin` folder is `C:\jdk\jdk1.8.0_301\bin`, append this to the `PATH` environment variable and also move it to the top position.
4. Create a new environment variable, `JAVA_HOME` and put `C:\jdk\jdk1.8.0_301` (i.e. the path, one level above the `bin` folder) as the value into it.
5. Finally, start a new cmd window and test the command, `java -version`.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Arvind Kumar Avinash. I got further along now, but now I'm getting the error:
"ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\jdk\bin

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation."

When I echo JAVA_HOME I get C:\jdk\bin

Comment: @RushwinJamdas - *When I echo JAVA_HOME I get C:\jdk\bin* - It is because you've set the wrong value into `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. As I have mentioned in the answer, the value of `JAVA_HOME` should be the path one level above that of the JDK `bin` folder. What is the path of your JDK bin folder? You can use Windows explorer to reach the JDK `bin` folder.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the \bin part and it worked.